# In a joomla template, how do I make the first page different from those with articles?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I'm creating a Joomla 1.6 template and I would like to make the first page different from the others (I say, the others with articles). What I expect is something like it:

```
<?php
if(this_page_link_to_an_artcile || this_page_is_not_the_main) {
   ?> <jdoc:include type="component" /> <?php
}
?>
```

I looked in one of the standard templates and got somewhat lost trying to find the "if" which makes   not be showed in some pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Is Frontpage?
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');

$frontpage = ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'featured')
$is_article = ($option == 'com_content');
if ($is_article && !$frontpage)
{
    // ...
}
```

(**EDIT**: now works in Joomla! 1.6)

(`$is_article || !$frontpage` should always return true ... because if it is not an article, it is not the frontpage. Depends on how you define "is an article", of course.)

Comment: it almost worked as your said, but JRequest::getCmd('view') was returning "featured" in the frontpage instead of "frontpage". I suppose it might be a difference from Joomla 1.5, right? Well, for now I'll suppose that "featured" identifies correctly the frontpage, since it seems to be working now. But if anyone still has a comment about it, I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have individual styling for each page, or a group of page, then you can add this into your template index.php /head:

```
 <?php $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();?>
```

After that, make a wrapper div that covers all your page in the body tags, for example:

```
<body>
<div class="<?php  echo $active->alias; ?> ">
----- PAGE CONTENT-----
</div>
</body>
```

That way you get to style any page you want with individual styling. For example, for "home" page, in you css file you should set properties for

```
.home .footer {}
```

to set properties for the .footer div that only appears on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple templates with joomla, and assign them to different menu items / pages.
You can for example have your main template (with articles) and another template only for the home page, that is ex. linked to "Home" menu item.

You can do the menu item/template assignment with the Template Manager.

Comment: but I wouldn't like to have two different templates, but just one. The same way some of the default templates work.

Comment: Hmmm I've never done it this way, but what could work is getting the ItemID and checking if it's the "Home" page and hide the Component and display modules or vice versa. ex. $menus = &JSite::getMenu();
$menu = $menus->getActive();
$itemid = $menu->id;

Comment: but how could I know a priori what is the id of the main page? For example, now in my page it's 435, but it's not sure it'll always be, right?

Comment: Yes that's the thing, but usually when you create a menu item, the itemid wil remain the same until the menu item is deleted. I see no reason to delete the "Home" menu-item and recreate it again. But you're right, this way requires hardcoding the itemid

Comment: any other sugestion? I would like to be able to get this same template and then use in another joomla site without having to change anything.

Comment: No sorry, the best I can think of is to instead using the ItemID, use the menu item's name, like "Home" as a reserved menu item name.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by different? Pages within Joomla look different based on which component and modules are being loaded. What content do you plan to have on your home page? You probably just need to change the default menu to a different type.

Unless there is a structural difference on the home page there is no need add more code, just change the menu type.

In order to accomodate structural difference from one page to another you need to make collapsible positions that only display when needed.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will also want to take advantage of the page class suffix parameter you can add to menu items. This allows you to add styles that are page specific. I usually add it to the BODY tag in my template index.php.

```
<?php
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$pageclass = "";
if (is_object( $active )) :
    $params = new JParameter( $active->params );
    $pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );
endif;
?>
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

Comment: I mean a totally different layout, with other columns placed in other spots.

Comment: You should still be able to do all of that within the template. It's a matter of setting up collapsible positions so that the page is built based on the positions that have content. I am adding a bit of code to my answer as an example.